Can I directly connect cold water supply line to a ever-hot hot water dispenser tank
I have an ever-hot hot water tank. The inlet of cold water comes from the faucet/dispense, which is chilled from the cold water chiller. Can I directly connect a cold  filter water to the tank?

Probably, but will make the heater work more to heat the water, maybe reducing its lifetime.  It takes money to chill water.  It takes more money to heat the chilled water, so at least doubling the cost to chill and heat.

how will you turn off the output?
